# Make query results links in PHP

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to turn some query results into click-able links through PHP. I'm a beginner and don't really know much. I'm working with Wordpress. Here's what I'm shooting for:
http://www.celebrything.com/

The right side bar is display the count results. I'd like the celebrity names to link to search links for each name. 
so the first should link to http://www.celebrything.com/?s=%22Tiger+Woods%22&search=Search

Here's the PHP I'm using to display my current results:

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT name, count FROM wp_celebcount');

    foreach($result as $row) {
        echo ''.$row->name.' - '.$row->count.' Posts <br/>';
    }
?>
```

The question is, how to I update this code to turn the names into search links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<a href="http://www.celebrything.com/?s='.urlencode($row->name).'&search=Search">'.$row->name.' - '.$row->count.' Posts </a><br/>';
```

Comment: Seriously.. You guys are amazing. Thanks a TON

Comment: Now I just have to figure out how to get my wordpress search working again. EGH. I installed google search, then removed it, and now wordpress search doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?s=<?php echo urlencode($row->name); ?>">
    <?php echo "{$row->name} ({$row->count} Posts)"; ?>
</a>
```

Note that `bloginfo` is a WordPress-specific function, so if you are working on a WordPress theme, I recommend using this rather than hard-coding the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing a link isn't really anything much more than what you're already doing. The important part is to make sure you properly escape relevant parts of the URL. That's what [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) is for.

```
foreach($result as $row) {
  echo '<a href="http://www.celebrything.com/?s=' .
    urlencode($row->name) . '&search=Search">' . $row->name .
    '</a> - ' . $row->count . ' Posts<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm assuming '^search=Search" is a typo..?  Should it be '&search=Search"  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT name, count FROM wp_celebcount');

    foreach($result as $row) {
        echo '<a href="?s='.urlencode($row->name).'&search=Search">'.$row->name.'</a> - '.$row->count.' Posts <br/>';
    }
?>
```